# CSS 'overflow: hidden' on parent element causing child styles to be cut off

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.util-truncate {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:focus-visible {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="util-truncate">
  <a href="#">This is a long link that will be truncated. This is a long link that will be truncated. This is a long link that will be truncated.</a>
</div>
```

**Problem:**

I am trying to apply a ring using box-shadow over the anchor element on focus. But because of the overflow hidden property on parent, the focus style is getting cut-off. As `truncate` is a utility class I cannot update any of it styles. Is there a way we could display the desired focus style properly for anchor element with only using CSS?

Following are the approaches I tried on anchor focus state,

1. box-shadow
2. outline (with offset)
3. box-shadow with z-index
4. box-shadow with inset (this approach is a bit close to expected output but not exact)
5. Using `before/after` pseudo selector

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: In your example, give the wrapper enough `padding` so that the link's styles have somewhere to bleed into.

Comment: @Ouroborus  That will fix only left, top, bottom. When I resize the window (from right to left) the focus style on right gets cut-off.

Comment: box-shadow and outline are not calculated as part of the element size, you can try a border or giving a margin with box-shadow or padding with box-shadow with inset

Comment: why the extra div? why not applying the logic to the link directly

Comment: @TemaniAfif This is a legacy code. I don't want to change the existing template. Just need to apply my required styles.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than cutting off the rendering, just limit the width of the `a` element. You don't even need a container div for that, just a `display: inline-block` to make sure it responds to `max-width`.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:focus-within {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:focus-visible {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is a long link that will be truncated. This is a long link that will be truncated. This is a long link that will be truncated.</a>
```

Comment: This won't work for my case. I need the wrapper class for different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Set `.util-truncate a { display: inline-block; max-width: 100%; }` and then add `.util-truncate a:focus { box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px blue; }` or pseudo-element:

```css
.util-truncate {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.util-truncate a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.util-truncate a:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="util-truncate">
  <a href="#">This is a long link that will be truncated. This is a long link that will be truncated. This is a long link that will be truncated.</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Increase the `line-height` and consider an inset `box-shadow`

```css
.util-truncate {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding: 2px;
}

a:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px blue inset;
}

a:focus-visible {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="util-truncate">
  <a href="#">This is a long link that will be truncated. This is a long link that will be truncated. This is a long link that will be truncated.</a>
</div>
```